# Binding DataTable to ComboBox, Returning Primary Key of Selected Item WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

This may seem a really simple question but I just cannot figure this out (I am new to XAML). I am populating a comboBox by binding it to a datatable. The primary key in my table is S_ID, I need to retrieve this value for the item selected on the SelectionChanged event so I can then load more details based on this value. I have tried int i = cboSites.SelectedItem, but get a type mismatch even though S_ID is an int. I can view the value in a DatarRowView in debug mode if I set i to type object, but cannot access the data any other way. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I have done lots of research and from what I read the code looks to be ok, but obviously isn't! By the way the combo box populates with the data absolutely fine. Thanks very much.

C#

```
try
{
     SqlDataAdapter sqlAd = new SqlDataAdapter();
     SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("SP_SelectAllSiteNamesForCust", sqlConn);
     sqlComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
     DataSet dSet = new DataSet();
     sqlAd.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
     sqlAd.Fill(dSet);
     DataTable sitesTable = dSet.Tables[0];
     cboSites.ItemsSource = sitesTable.DefaultView;

 }
```

XAML

```
 <ComboBox Height="28" IsEditable="True" Margin="630,15,28,10" 
           Name="cboSites" TabIndex="6" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
           DisplayMemberPath="S_Name" 
           SelectedItem="{Binding Path=S_ID}"  
           SelectionChanged="cboSites_SelectionChanged" />
```

SQL Stored Proc

```
SELECT 
[S_ID],
[S_Name]
FROM
[dbo].[tbl_Site]
WHERE [C_ID] = @CUSTID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a type mismatch because every item in your collection is like a row in a table from DataView you are binding to. So in your cboSites_SelectionChanged you can get S_ID something like this:

```
var s_id = int.Parse(((DataRowView)cboSites.SelectedItem)["S_ID"].ToString());
```

Here you are casting `cboxSites.SelectedItem` to `DataRowView` type, then using indexer to get S_ID value. Then you just convert that value to string and parsing it into integer variable.

Comment: That's awesome it works, thanks so much. I couldn't have worked out how to cast that type on my own! I thought the idea of binding in WPF was to do most things in XAML and to make things easier. This just seems a little complicated in order to get that value! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="S_Name" 
          SelectedValuePath="S_ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Int_Property_In_The_ViewModel}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I tried that and now if I debug with the following code - var i = cboSitesForTurbine.SelectedValue - in SelectionChanged I get i = null ...  Any ideas?